# Why is there a Jewish site on StackExchange and not a Christian one?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

*Statistically* people who call themselves Christian outnumber people who call themselves Jews. Why is there a site dedicated to Judaism and not Christianity (based on the numbers)? Surely there would be a sufficient number of people to moderate and answer questions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is one at https://christianity.stackexchange.com/